# How can I spoof Via Header in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, http-headers, spoofing

I am working on this http header spoofer for both request and response to preserve privacy.

Is it really worth it to spoof via header to preserve privacy ? Per my understanding via header tells the server about intermediate routers between the server and the client but I tried to view the traffic in "HTTP live header" not every website use via header so when do we need via header ?
Between me and the Google let say intermediate routers are a,b,c. me and Yahoo x,y,z at time x. Would these routers be different at time y?

I have this code below for Set-Cooie field. I tried replacing it with "via" but it doesn't work.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details)
{

        details.responseHeaders[details.responseHeaders.length] = {name: "set-cookie", value: "gadggsdsgsdgsgdgdggddgdgd11212"};
        return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};

},{urls:["<all_urls>"],types:["xmlhttprequest","sub_frame"]},
["responseHeaders","blocking"]);
```

Comment: Routers operate on a lower layer than the HTTP protocol, they do not touch HTTP headers. Proxy servers might. Routers and proxies might be different for every request.

Comment: How does stripping the Via header benefit privacy? There's still is (and needs to be) enough information in the request to identify and thereby get the response back to your computer after all.